# MySQL Update table column comparing two tables

Tags: mysql

```
Users table has following columns
-----------------------------------
Users isMember
A     Yes
B     Yes
C     Yes
X     Yes
Y     Yes
Z     Yes

ValidSubcription table the following details
-------------------------
Users  isSubActive
A      Yes  
X      Yes
Y      Yes
```

Now based on this details I want to change the isMember column in Users table and set it from Yes to No for the users not present in ValidSubscription table.

```
output should be like this

Users isMember
A     Yes
B     No
C     No
X     Yes
Y     Yes
Z     No
```

Comment: do you need result in select query or you want to update table ?

Comment: @AmitVerma I want to update the Users table

Comment: your topic title says create new table. If you need update then I will update query.

Comment: @AmitVerma my bad , changed the title, requirement is to update the existing table.

Comment: Query update to update the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just update your table using a `LEFT JOIN`, which will update all the rows in the Users table even if they don't have a corresponding line in the ValidSubscription table.

The update of isMember uses `COALESCE` which will use the value of isSubActive if it exists for that row or 'No' if it doesn't.

```
UPDATE Users u
LEFT JOIN ValidSubscription s
  ON u.Users = s.Users
SET isMember = COALESCE(isSubActive, 'No')
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a283f/1)

...and always, back your data up before running updates given to you from random pepole on the Internet ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the required data like this. You can insert the new selected result into your table.

```
UPDATE Users 
SET Users.isMember = COALESCE(V.isSubActive, 'No')
FROM Users U
LEFT OUTER JOIN ValidSubcription V ON U.[User] = V.[User]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using Joins and Coalesce, you can update the required table like this:

```
UPDATE `users`
SET `users`.`isMember`="No"
WHERE `users`.`user` NOT IN (
    SELECT `validsubscription`.`user` 
    FROM `validsubscription` 
    WHERE `validsubscription`.`isSubActive`="Yes"
    );
```

I've changed the `users` column to `user` to avoid ambiguity with the `users` table but everything else should be the same as in the given tables.